# Can't push in parse, says installation are outdated

Tags: parse-platform

Hi have worked with parse for saving data. But notification is something i am stuck with. I am not able figure out what's going wrong.

I have done all the receiver registrations and so my device also gets registered in the installation table but while sending push from web console it says "push sent 0" looking into the description of each push it shows that "OUTDATED DEVICE - The records on this installation are outdated, the user might have uninstalled the app."
But I just did the registration.

I am going mad with this...no clue in what am I doing wrong.

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


Parse.initialize(this, applicationId, clientKey);
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, HomeActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: As I can't upload images...here are the link to some screenshots
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8XmGD9UhgQXbUFnd3RMamFxcUk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8XmGD9UhgQXakZxNjVIbnNraWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now...

Comment: I figured out it wasn't working because I had set a suffixe to the package in my debug build type. Lost 2 hours of my life. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gyome can you pls elaborate on what changes you made...a glimpse of what was there in your gradle file

Comment: I simply removed debug{applicationIdSuffix ".debug"} since I didn't really need it. If you need to keep it, I guess you should change the package name you declare in your manifest (and anywhere else if necessary) for the Parse stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am greatly thankful to @Gyome for the hint and that was the exact thing where I was going wrong. I just made the change in my gradle file regarding the package name and everything was butter smooth.
I got to know..as I checked my release builds are going fine.

Comment: That did the trick! In mine was in manifest, I've changed the "C2D_MESSAGE" permission to my package name, but I didn't notice that the next line had the same package declaration. Changed and then worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have this

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I was missing this and parse could not use my account to generate the keys.